# Updating Repositories

Tags: system-installation

I keep getting this message everytime I install apps or after running sudo apt update

Doesn't seem to prevent me installing if I ignore. 
Sudo apt-get autoremove doesn't fix this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I apologise for putting this as an answer. I think you may have forgotten to post the error message you are getting?

I would run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` if there is an issue with updating repositories.

Alternatively, if you have had a previous apt install fail, you can resolve it with `sudo apt -f install` which will often fix things.